# Getting values of Multiple Control ID's in ASP.net Listview and passing it to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

I have several labels in a listview control in a ASP.net page and I need to access the values of these labels in JavaScript to display data from a custom page for each label / record in a div (mouse-over effect). I can access the first lblID's value by assigning it to a variable in the JavaScript but I need to know how I can access the rest (let's assume there are 10 records in the listview for this example).

Each label will have a different value e.g. 1 , 5, 24 which needs to be passed to an ASP.net file in the JavaScript to get the text for the mouseover. The page sys_get_rankings.aspx?id=1 display the HTML for the mouse-over.

Getting the value of one label (ctl00_cpMain_ListView1_ctrl0_lblID) is not my problem, but getting the rest since the number of labels will change every time. The purpose of the JavaScript is to create a mouse-over effect when the user hovers over a certain element with a class called 'button'.

Herewith the code snippets;

**The JavaScript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').CreateBubblePopup({
        position: 'top',
        align: 'center',
        innerHtml: '<img src="images/loading.gif" style="border:0px; vertical-align:middle; margin-right:10px; display:inline;" />loading!',
        innerHtmlStyle: { color:'#FFFFFF', 'text-align':'center' },
        themeName: 'all-black',
        themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'
      });
    $('.button').mouseover(function(){
            var button = $(this);
            var x =  document.getElementById('ctl00_cpMain_ListView1_ctrl0_lblID').innerText;
            $.get('sys_get_rankings.aspx?Id=' + x, function(data) {
                button.SetBubblePopupInnerHtml(data, false); 
                };
            }); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**HTML / ASP.net Code**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsUsers">
...
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:
bold; color: #2661d1;" class="button"><%# Eval("Player_Name") %></span>

<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true" ><span style="color: #FFF">      
<%#Eval("TheUserID")%></span></asp:Label>
...
</asp:ListView>
```

I hope this makes sense and would appreciate it if any can shed some light on this!

Comment: Getting the value of one label (ctl00_cpMain_ListView1_ctrl0_lblID) IS your problem. One of many, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea of how I would approach this.

First, put a `CssClass` value on your Label controls (say, "label") so that you will be able to get to it without worrying about what the id value created by ASP.NET is.

Second, in your javascript for the button mouseover, you could use something like `button.next('.label')` to get a reference to that label. This assumes that the .button span is right next to the label.

Then you can get the innerText or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add custom attribute to your span, say userid:

```
<span userid="<%#Eval("TheUserID")%>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #2661d1;" class="button">
```

then in JS code you can just do the following:

```
var x = $(this).attr('userid');
```

Thus you are not tying yourself to your DOM structure (someday you may decide not to display the ID, so you'll have no label with it, but the solution will still work).